# Determine the end of the string in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to work on a Lexer which would determine whether the input has String/Integer/Double/etc in it. I've successfully determined whether i'm dealing with any other than string but i'm having trouble figuring out how to handle string part.

So let's say i have three inputs:

```
input = "\"asd\""
input2 = "\"The string \"String\" is really great\"5432"
input3 = "\"The string \"String\" is really great\"5432"\One more\""

Expected output from:
input = <STRING:asd> //Works with current code
input2 = <STRING:The string "String" is really great><INTEGER 5432> //Broken
input3 = <STRING:The string "String" is really great><INTEGER 5432> <STRING:One more>//ALSO BROKEN
```

The output handling is done and working so this is not the problem, the problem is to handle how the string ends.
It's easy to handle strings which does not contain quotation mark and this is currently how i've handled it:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 1;
    pos++;
    current = input.charAt(pos);
    boolean last = false;
    char next = input.charAt(pos+1);
    while (current != '"'){
        sb.append(current);
        pos++;
        current = input.charAt(pos);
        next = input.charAt(pos+1);
    }
    tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.STRING,sb.toString()));
```

Now with my code the problem appears when the first quotation marks appear in String (see input2 or input3 for example). I'm checking through the input char by char and the else-if branch is determined by the quotation marks beginning, that's why there's a pos++ and current update (which refers to a 'T' char in input2 for example).

How could i determine whether the string has ended (Whether the 5432 is an integer in input2 not the part of the first string)?

Comment: Have you tried the `input.length` property in order to loop until you reach the length of the string you are parsing?

Comment: Umm, i could do that, but i don't see how it could help me. In case i have a string "Numbers are "5324"" how do i determine that it's one string not STRING,INTEGER,STRING.

Comment: And what a about the function `split()` in order to directly obtain your string between  " char?

Comment: I resolved the issue another way right now, i changed the way i mark the syntax, if it's the beginning or end of the string in java i use `\"` otherwise `\\\"`

Answer (score 0):

So basically according to Lexer, output STRING,INT,STRING from input 3 would be correct in my case, because using the marker `\"`doesen't just cut it, i have to create a quotation mark notation in the string, so for that `\\\"`cuts it: first of the two backslashes will display a backslash itself `\`and backslash and quotation mark `\"` will display quotation mark in string. In total the displayed string would be `\"` which is simply a notation for quotation mark.